# How to access a parameter value in the Configuration stage of a Spinnaker pipeline?

Tags: spinnaker

I've added a parameter, `SERVER_PROPERTY_NAME`, to a Spinnaker pipeline and have a stage conditional on that parameter being set. The condition is `${!SERVER_PROPERTY_NAME.isEmpty()}` but it's evaluating as `false` even when the parameter is set. What's the right way to access the value of the parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `${!parameters.SERVER_PROPERTY_NAME.isEmpty()}`.